# Azure Git Hub Deployment Issues

Tags: php, azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I have been following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-php-mysql-app

However the only difference is that I am trying to upload my own webapp not the demo 'Laravel Tasks'

I have changed the PHP Version from 7.0 to 7.3

When I get the the Git Push Azure Master step everything works until I get this error.

> remote: Copying files to destination directory '/home/site/wwwroot'...
>   remote: .........................................................................
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/composer": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/dep": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/jp.php": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/jsonlint": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/php-parse": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/phpunit": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/psysh": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/validate-json": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: rsync: failed to set times on "/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bin/var-dump-server": Operation not permitted (1)
>   remote: ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
>   remote: rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

Are you deploying to Windows or Linux flavour of Azure App Service? Couple of things to try:

Disconnect and re-connect the deployment source to the primary repository and see if that helps. 
If you’re deploying to a staging slot, try deploying to a production slot.

Kindly try to install the composer via start up script. 
By default, [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) doesn't run Composer. To enable Composer automation during Kudu deployment, you need to supply a [custom deployment script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script).

Also, kindly take a look at the helpful blog which contains things you should know when using WebApp for Containers - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/